# Arithmetic problem Ivan and Adeline

Tags: arithmetic

Ivan and Adeline are in a classroom with a chalkboard. They are standing on different halves of the board, and on each half, the number $2$ is written. When Ivan's teacher gives a signal, Ivan multiplies the number on his side of the board by $-2$ and writes the answer on the board, erasing the number he started with. Adeline does the same on each signal, except that she multiplies by $2$. The teacher gives 10 signals in total. How many times (including the initial number) do Ivan and Adeline have the same number written on the board (including at the beginning)?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you attempted to write out their numbers and compare? That's a good first step.

Comment: @ddswsd did you even try this problem? if you did, where did you get stuck? -1 since it appears that you put in 0 effort

Comment: I'm thinking it is 5. I wrote a list out for Ivan 2,-4,8,-16,32,-64,128,-256,512,-1024,2048 and for Adeline 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee check again

Comment: It says including the initial number, so maybe the answer is 6

Comment: In general, if teacher gives $n$ signals, $1+[n/2]$ times numbers repeat.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is

**0)** $2 \quad2$

**1)** $-4 \quad 4$

**2)** $8 \quad8$

...

**10)** $2^{11} \quad 2^{11}$

thus **6 times** in total (including the start).

In general after the $k^{th}$ signal we have on the board:

$$(-1)^{k}2^{k+1} \quad2^{k+1}$$

and thus they are equals if and only if for $k=0$ or even.

Comment: This includes the initial number. I agree. Thank you

Comment: @ddswsd Yes of course, we need to strat from 0 and thu we have 6 equalities.